# Get a vector given velocity and angle

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a plane's velocity, and its angle relative to the north. I'm having a difficulty representing it as a vector $(x, y)$ in my code.

Since the velocity is the vector's length (I suppose?) it should be equal to $ \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but how do I convert the angle I have into a formula?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take the opportunity to take the [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour), if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [how to ask](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and write down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use trigonometry. Assuming that $x$ is positive towards East and $y$ is positive towards North and that the angle $\theta$ is in radians and it increases counter-clockwise:

$$\begin{align}
x & = - \sin(\theta) \\
y & = \cos(\theta)
\end{align}$$

Comment: And if the angle increases clockwise, would that just be x=sin(a)?

Comment: @user2979612 Yes, you're correct.

Comment: If this answers your question, feel free to accept my answer. There is a green button next to it.